# pandas dataframe to matrix dtype errors

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I find that the same set of commands work differently in two cases. Can anyone tell why the second case extracts integers whereas the first does not. I want to replicate behavior of case I.

Case I: works

```
<<< df = pd.read_csv('...csv file 1 ')
<<< df = df.ix[:,[0, 7, 8, 11, 20, 24, 25]]
<<< datFm = df.values 
<<< datFm[1,:5]
   array([413190.2978, 1, 100000, 93.1, 0.0], dtype=object)
```

Case II: has strings

```
<<< dfPL = pd.read_csv('  csv file 2 ')
<<< PLRT = dfPL.ix[:,17]
<<< PLRT_M = PLRT.values
<<< PLRT_M[:5]
 array(['-8.85', '250.72', '1,220.25', '124.89', '11.21'], dtype=object)
```

Both the csv files were excel files saved in csv format.

Comment: did you pass the `thousands` argument to `pd.read_csv`?  I'm guessing the commas are throwing off your second case.

Comment: I tried read_csv('file.csv',thousands=','). Get exactly the same output.  I then used excel to remove the thousands commas.  So now I get array of strings without thousands commas.!!

Comment: I took a close look at ALL the data elements in the column (50,000 of them) and found some division by zero errors etc in the excel sheet. That probably explains it!

Comment: @user2133151 If you solved your problem you can answer your own question, and mark it as the accepted answer so that people won't think this question is unanswered.

Comment: I tried that but got a message essentially saying I have to wait a few more hrs. So I added the comment....